# How to relay keyboard events from one window to another

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard-events

I have two windows, each with the HWND of the other.

Window A contains the application and UI logic and has some UI elements.

Window B also has UI elements, but I want it to act like a terminal. Right now window B is just rendering another view into Window A's state, and has no UI or application logic.

When window B is in focus, I want it's keyboard data to get redirected to window A, so it can handle the input logic, make changes to the UI, that then get reflected in Window B.

The code that manages window B is C++, loosely following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/creating-a-window. Window A is it's own beast (Unity Engine, standalone build).

I considered SendInput() or PostMessage(), but since Window A is out of focus, it never gets it.

I can always fall back to just catching every keyboard event in Window B, and using custom messaging logic to send those events to Window A, but that seems really wasteful. I feel like this is a solved problem.